# Analytic solution rather than graphical

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can this concentration $C$ be solved algebraically? My textbook example only solves it graphically which is not helpful.

The concentration $C$ of a drug in the bloodstream at t minutes after injection is given by

$$C= 0.03te^{-0.01t} ~ \text{mg/cm}^{3}$$

In how many minutes will the concentration reach $0.5$? The textbook graphical answer is estimated as ~20 minutes.
/Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25557/find-intersection-of-linear-and-logarithmic-lines
That question is related to yours. Algebraic manipulations can lead you to the form in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Rewriting the equation as
\begin{align}
\tfrac3{100}\,t\exp(-\tfrac1{100}\,t)
&=\tfrac12
,\\
-\tfrac1{100}\,t\exp(-\tfrac1{100}\,t)
&=-\tfrac16
,
\end{align}
we can express the solution in terms of 
[Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) 
as

\begin{align}
-\tfrac1{100}\,t
&=\operatorname{W}(-\tfrac16)
,\\
t&=-100\,\operatorname{W}(-\tfrac16)
\end{align}

and since $-\tfrac1{\mathrm{e}}<-\tfrac16<0$,
we have two real solutions,

\begin{align}
t_0&=-100\,\operatorname{W}_0(-\tfrac16)
\approx 20.45
,\\
t_1&=-100\,\operatorname{W}_{-1}(-\tfrac16)
\approx 283.31
.
\end{align}

For example, in Python, we can get this result
with

```
from scipy.special import lambertw as W
print -100*W(-1/6.), -100*W(-1/6.,-1)
# (20.448144934-0j) (283.314789205-0j)
```

Compare this with the graphic approach:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved, but you need to use the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), in general the problem

$$
at e^{-b} =c
$$

has solution

$$
t = -\frac{W(-bc/a)}{b}
$$

Replace $a = 0.03$, $b = 0.01$ and $c = 0.5$ and the [solution is](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-ProductLog(-0.01%20*%200.5%20%2F%200.03)%20%2F%200.01)

$$
t = 20.44 ~{\rm min}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Without Lambert function, consider that you look for the zero of function
$$f(t)=\frac{3}{100} t\, e^{-t/100}-\frac{1}{2}$$ Compute the derivatives
$$f'(t)=-\frac{3 e^{-t/100} (t-100)}{10000}\qquad f''(t)=\frac{3 e^{-t/100} (t-200)}{1000000}$$
The first derivative cancels when $t=100$ and then $f(100)=\frac{3}{e}-\frac{1}{2} >0$ and $f''(100)=-\frac{3}{10000 e} <0$.

So, there are two roots such that $0 < t_1 <100$ and $t_2>100$.

Approximate the function using a $[2,2]$ Padé approximant built at $t=100$ to get
$$f(x)=\frac{\left(\frac{3}{e}-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{50 e}-\frac{1}{300}\right)
   (t-100)-\left(\frac{7}{720000}+\frac{11}{120000 e}\right)
   (t-100)^2 } { 1+\frac{1}{150}(t-100)+\frac{7 }{360000}(t-100)^2}$$ Solve the quadratic equation corresponding to the numerator and get, as an *approximation*
$$t=\frac{27600-1000 e+\sqrt{777600000-103680000 e-4320000 e^2}}{132+14 e}$$ which is $\approx 272.962$, not too bad since, as already given by g.kov, the exact solution is $\approx 283.315$